# Can we run single workflow instance for multiple item changed or created?

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow

I have created a SharePoint Designer 2010 approval workflow and I am starting this workflow on item created and modified . Now when I am adding and updating multiple items it is starting workflow for each item but I want to start only one workflow for all items.

I think this is not possible but I want to make sure.

Is this possible? If yes then how?

Comment: What do you need your workflow to do?

Comment: I want to modify  more than one item and trigger one instance of all modified items.My problem is for custom approval workflow and i don't want to approve each item , I want to approve all modified items in one time.

Answer (score 1):

A list workflow can be associated to list type. We can set workflow to run

1. Manual
2. On Create
3. On Update

A workflow once activated gets executed on top of a list item. So if the workflow is set to run on item create, then the worflow will get executed for each new item.

There is nothing like only a single instance for all list items (Even logically it doesn't make sense)

Comment: My problem is for custom approval workflow and i don't want to approve each item , I want to approve all modified items in one time . approver person does not want  to click on each individual item ,then approve. He wants to view all approve request and Approve all item at a time . please reply if you have any solution...